# Non-homotopical manifolds with same de Rham cohomology

Tags: differential-topology

I am searching for manifolds $M$ and $N$ with different homotopy type such that their de Rham cohomology is isomorphic as rings.
It would, of course, be enough to find $M$ and $N$ with different $\pi_1$.

Comment: The same as what? Isomorphic as vector spaces? As rings?

Comment: You might want to see the same question at mathoverflow:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53399/spaces-with-same-homotopy-and-homology-groups-that-are-not-homotopy-equivalent

Comment: @levap As rings, thank you. I actually can't think right now of an example of manifolds with isomorphic de Rham cohomology as vector spaces but different ring structure, so that also would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the examples here are closed manifolds (compact without boundary); as Jason DeVito points out, you can simplify this a bit if you allow noncompact manifolds.

You can do this as soon as dimension 3. One nice fact is that if $M \to N$ is a finite covering map, then it induces an injection $H^*(N) \to H^*(M)$; applying this to $M = S^3$, we see that any orientable quotient of $M$ has the same de Rham cohomology of $M$. One simple case is $\Bbb{RP}^3$, but there are also the many [lens spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space).

One particularly worthwhile example is the [Poincare sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar.C3.A9_homology_sphere), defined to be $SO(3)/I$, where $I$ is the isometry group of the icosahedron. This doesn't just have the same de Rham cohomology as $S^3$, it has the same *singular homology* - but is still not homotopy equivalent.

As mentioned in the comment above, the simplest example of two non-homotopy-equivalent manifolds with the same homology, higher homotopy groups, *and* fundamental group are $S^2 \times S^2$ and $\Bbb{CP}^2 \# \overline{\Bbb{CP}^2}$; one can distinguish them via the ring structure on cohomology. (But the *de Rham* cohomology rings are isomorphic, like you want.)

Comment: You can do it in dim 2:  $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Also, I think your second sentence needs some kind of orientability hypothesis (which you mentioned later on).

Comment: @JasonDeVito Ah, I was thinking of everything being closed. I'll add that in. I don't believe that result requires any sort of orientability.

Comment: But the covering $S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ does not induce a bijection $H^\ast(N)\rightarrow H^\ast(M)$.  Also, even for orientable things, you need a finite sheeted covering (which, of course, is automatic for closed manifolds).  Or perhaps I'm misinterpreting what you wrote?

Comment: Also, I believe $S^2\times S^2$ and $\mathbb{C}P^2\sharp\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$ have the same rational homotoyp type.  If so, their de Rham cohomology rings agree.  On the other hand, I think $S^2\times S^2$ and $\mathbb{C}P^2\sharp \mathbb{C}P^2$ have different de Rham cohomology rings.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Oops! I thought one thing and wrote another. I meant to say injection and finite cover... really nasty mistake, thanks for calling me out. I believe bijection is still false in the oriented case but I don't have an example on a minute's thought.

Comment: I agree that bijection is probably false even when oriented and finite sheeted, but I also don't know of an example.  (But I do agree about the injection, and that it doesn't need orientability)

Comment: @Jason: They do have the same de Dham cohomology rings, but different integral cohomology rings.

Comment: Then I guess I misinterpreted what the OP was asking - I agree that integrally the cohomology rings differ.  Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: @JasonDeVito No worries at all... I don't actually know how to prove that $2\Bbb{CP}^2$ have the same homotopy groups as $S^2 \times S^2$. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, that is true: $S^3\times S^3$ is a principal $T^2$ bundle over both of them, so one can use the LES in homotopy groups.  This is clear for $S^2\times S^2$ using the Hopf bundle.  For $\mathbb{C}P^2\times \mathbb{C}P^2$, the result, as far as I know, goes back to Totaro (Cheeger manifolds and the classification of biquotients).

Comment: Huh, that's wild. Somehow homotopy groups don't do half the job the cohomology ring does for s.c. 4-manifolds.

Comment: Incidentally, according to https://open.library.ubc.ca/cIRcle/collections/ubctheses/831/items/1.0079494, the covering $S^2\rightarrow S^2\rightarrow S^2\times S^2/ ( (x,y) \sim -(x,y)$ is a $2$-sheeted covering of orientable manifolds, but the second Betti number of the quotient is $0$ - so there's our counterexample to "bijection"

Comment: This is great, Mike and Jason. Thank you both.

Comment: @Jason We're very silly. There are finite covers of closed oriented surfaces that give counterexamples :)

Comment: @Mike:  Wow.  Just wow.  (I guess my counterexample has the added bonus of using a universal cover.  Yeah, that's why I searched long and hard for it ;-) )